# Two questions on cyclotomic extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

For which $n,m$ is $\Bbb Q(w)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta)$, where $w$ and $\zeta$ are primitive $n$ and $m$th roots of unity respectively.

And, what are the cyclotomic extensions containing $i$?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: I've changed your choice of letter `p` to the Greek letter $\zeta$, because far too often the former is understood to be a prime number, especially in the context of cyclotomy. I hope you don't mind the stylistic change.

Answer (score 3):

the answer is :"if and only if n|m or n|2m with m odd"